# Mac Safari DIVs height is larger than other browers

Tags: html, css, macos, flexbox, height

I am having a problem which is only MAC,I'm using flexbox to organize my code but some divs are getting larger on Safari browser even though I've added -webkit- to my css code.

**CSS**

```
.appt-row { 
    display: -webkit-box; 
    display: -moz-box;  
    display: -ms-flexbox;  
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display: flex; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    -webkit-box-direction:normal; 
    flex-direction: row; 
    text-align: justify; 
    margin-bottom: 3%; 
}
```

Comment: plz send the css code?

Comment: Do you use https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/?

Comment: @MrLine No I don't

Comment: your safari browser version?. Meanwhile you can try deleting those comments in css block and check again

Comment: Safari version 12.1.2

Comment: @Soothran I did and nothing happened

Comment: check this in chrome emulator by setting custom width and height(1920px and 1080px).

Answer (score 0):

```
 @supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
     specific safari css code...
 }
```

This is a workaround for safari.